# Setting ngIf dynamically on a form required field with a custom directive

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

First of all I'm kinda new to Angular. I've created a directive that is being used in my form-group div in the HTML. This contains a required input. The ideia of this directive is to check if the entire div will be shown based on a scope value.

*Visually, this works as expected but...* when setting the **ng-if** directive to a false value, the form submission still gives an error as **a required value is missing** when the form doesn't even contain that input anymore.

This is my code:

```js
// My Directive
app.directive("showCountry", function ($compile) {

    var linkFunction = function (scope, element, attributes) {

        var testingVariable = scope.testingVariable;

        if (testingVariable) {
            switch (testingVariable.toLowerCase()) {
                case "A":
                    // Do nothing, keep the div visible.
                    break;
                default:
                    // Hide the entire div.
                    attributes.$set("ngIf", false);               
               compile(element)(scope);
                    break;
            }
        }
    };

    return {
        restrict: "A",
        link: linkFunction
    };
});
```

```html
<!-- My HTML with required field using my directive -->
<div class="form-group" show-country>
 <label class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 control-label">
  Country
 </label>
 <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6">
  <input name="country" type="text" placeholder="Country" ng-model="country" ng-required="true"/>
 </div>
</div>
```

Thank you guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a scope variable `validate`and make it false in the condition,

```
if (testingVariable.toLowerCase()) {
    switch (testingVariable.toLowerCase()) {
        case "A":
            // Do nothing, keep the div visible.
            break;
        default:
            // Hide the entire div.
            scope.validate = false;
            attributes.$set("ngIf", false);               
                      $compile(element)(scope);
            break;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="test">
<form name="myForm">
The country input is hided and animation wil not occur
<div class="form-group" show-country validate="validate">
 <label class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 control-label">
  Country
 </label>
 <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6">
  <input name="country" type="text" placeholder="Country" ng-model="country" ng-required="true" ng-if="validate"/>
 </div>
</div>
</form>
<h1>{{myForm.country.$error}}
<script>
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.directive("showCountry", function ($compile) {

    var linkFunction = function (scope, element, attributes) {

        var testingVariable = scope.testingVariable;
  console.log(testingVariable.toLowerCase())
        if (testingVariable.toLowerCase()) {
            switch (testingVariable.toLowerCase()) {
                case "A":
                    // Do nothing, keep the div visible.
                    break;
                default:
                    // Hide the entire div.
                    scope.validate = false;
                    attributes.$set("ngIf", false);               
               $compile(element)(scope);
                    break;
            }
        }
    };

    return {
        restrict: "A",
        link: linkFunction
    };
});
app.controller("test", function ($scope) {
  $scope.testingVariable = 'false';

});

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

[Here is the DEMO with validation Occuring, **Your scenario**](https://plnkr.co/edit/QlaBb0KJKb02Q32Nw2zo?p=preview)

[DEMO with novalidation, **Required answer**](https://plnkr.co/edit/d75SKrOMqPVeZ8TKpXld?p=preview)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. What if I had more than one required field? What could I do in order to avoid the creation of another validation variable?

Comment: you can use the same variable in different fields for the same condition. Howz your scenario?

Comment: I have this code but I have two required fields. If I use the same variable then one of the inputs will not be shown.

Comment: If you check the input, I added `ng-if="validate" ` to it, if you omit it, It will work as you need for other input,